# Não consigo reproduzir os dados do governo da PNAD 2013 a partir dos microdados

Tags: r

O governo anunciou ano passado o resultado da PNAD 2013, nele aparece que há [85,3% das casa tinham água encanada.](http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/economia/noticia/2014-09/mais-de-85%25-das-casas-t%C3%AAm-%C3%A1gua-encanada-diz-IBGE)

Baixei os microdados da PNAD e com o R tentei reproduzir a análise segue abaixo o código:

```
setwd( "/saneamento_basico/")

# pacotes
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(xlsx)
library(descr)
library(survey)

# paths
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dicionarioPath <- "PNAD/Dicionаrios e input/Dicionаrio de variаveis de domicбlios - PNAD 2013.xls"
pnadPath <- "PNAD/Dados/DOM2013.txt"
pnadCsvOut <- "PNAD/DOM2013.txt"

# traduz arquivo
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# dicionario
dicionario <- read.xlsx(dicionarioPath, sheetIndex = 1, 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                        startRow = 4)[,1:3]

dicionario <- dicionario[complete.cases(dicionario),]
colnames(dicionario) <- c("start", "size", "var")
dicionario$end <- as.numeric(dicionario$start) + dicionario$size - 1

# traducao
 fwf2csv(fwffile = pnadPath, 
         csvfile = pnadCsvOut,
         names = dicionario$var,
          begin = dicionario$start,
          end = dicionario$end)

# le e formata pnad
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pnad <- read.csv(pnadCsvOut, sep = '\t')

# "Forma de abastecimento     de água"
coluna_formaDeAbastecimentoDeAgua <- "V4624" 
colunas_pesoDomicilio <- "V4611" # "Peso do domicílio"
strat <- "V4602" # "Estrato" 
id <- "V4618" # "PSU - Unidade primária de amostragem"

 # retira quem tem NA nos pesos
 pnad <- pnad[!is.na(pnad[,colunas_pesoDomicilio]),]
 # retira quem tem NA em forma de abastecimento
 pnad <- pnad[!is.na(pnad[,coluna_formaDeAbastecimentoDeAgua]),]

 # tranforma quem tem agua encanada em 1 e os outros em 0

 temAguaEncanada <- as.numeric(pnad[,coluna_formaDeAbastecimentoDeAgua] == 1)
 pnad[,coluna_formaDeAbastecimentoDeAgua] <- temAguaEncanada 

 sample.pnad <- svydesign(ids = ~V4618, 
                          strata = ~V4602,
                          weights = ~V4611, 
                          data = pnad,
                          nest = TRUE)

 # para evitar erro "has only one PSU at stage 1"
 options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")

 # deveria retornar a porcentagem de que​m tem​​ agua encanada (0.853)
 # mas retorna 0.83964
 svymean(~V4624, design = sample.pnad, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Com isso obtenho o resultado de 84%. 1,3% a menos que o governo.

Essa é a primeira vez que uso o pacote survey, então queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas o dicionário da PNAD tem um problema: duas variáveis compartilham caracteres do banco de dados (a UF e Cidade). Confere se no teu arquivo não tem isso. Se tiver, apaga a linha do UF (tem que ser essa) do dicionário e tenta de novo!

Comment: Pequena correção: É UF e Número de Controle (V0102), e não UF e Município

Comment: Rodei o teu código e não é esse o problema... talvez nem haja problema: no próprio IBGE diz que o percentual é 83,96% (http://goo.gl/qAzi1X)

Comment: Muito obrigado @Rcoster. Você tem alguma ideia porque esse número diverge do dados do governo?

Comment: Me parece ser erro das fontes dos jornais. [Um site](http://www.bahianoticias.com.br/noticia/160521-pnad-2013-85-3-das-casas-tem-agua-encanada-64-tem-coleta-de-esgoto.html), por exemplo, cita a Folha como fonte do valor 85,6%. Mas no [próprio site da folha](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/infograficos/2014/09/117197-veja-os-principais-indicadores-da-pnad.shtml) o valor é 86,4%. A EBC é uma estatal de notícias, mas não é quem faz a pesquisa. Seus dados tem que bater com os do IBGE, e aparentemente estão corretos.

Comment: Sinalizei a pergunta para ser fechada pois não há problema no código, o resultado bate com a referência oficial. O erro está nas outras fontes, não há dúvida sobre programação aqui.