# O número de controle V0102 da PNAD não corresponde ao código de municípios do IBGE. Como fazer para unir os bancos?

Tags: csv, merge, txt

Olá!

Estou trabalhando com os suplementos sobre segurança alimentar da `pnad04`, `pnad09` e `pnad13` do IBGE e com dois outros bancos do IPEA, um sobre PIB municipal `ipea.pib` e outro sobre investimentos em programas sociais por município `ipea.ps`. Com isso, estou tentando formar um grande banco de dados em que eu possa integrar as variáveis que me interessam dos três bancos utilizando `merge(pnad13, ipea.pib, ipea.ps, by="V0102")`, onde `V0102` é a variável "número de controle" que representa o código dos municípios na PNAD. Ou seja, trabalho com os municípios como referência. O problema é que ao transformar os dados, dicionário e input baixados do IBGE no banco da PNAD, `V0102` tem 8 números quando deveria ter apenas 7! Este problema já foi reportando em comentário anteriormente, mas a sugestão dada não soluciona o problema: [Não consigo reproduzir os dados do governo da PNAD 2013 a partir dos microdados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89060/n%C3%A3o-consigo-reproduzir-os-dados-do-governo-da-pnad-2013-a-partir-dos-microdados). O código oficial dos municípios brasileiros tem 7 números, conforme consta nos bancos do IPEA e neste link: http://www.msystemmirassol.com.br/imagens/Codigos_IBGE.pdf.

```
pnad13[1,3]
[1] 11000015

# Este é o código de Alta Floresta do Oeste (RO) na PNAD (contém 8 números)
# Mas nos outros dois bancos o código de Alta Floresta do Oeste (RO) tem 7 números:

11000015 %in% ipea.pib$V0102
[1] FALSE
11000015 %in% ipea.ps$V0102
[1] FALSE

# Se retirarmos um 0 "extra" chegamos a seu valor verdadeiro:

1100015 %in% ipea.pib$V0102
[1] TRUE
1100015 %in% ipea.ps$V0102
[1] TRUE

# Outro exemplo:

35008270 %in% pnad13$V0102
[1] TRUE
length(which(pnad13$V0102==35008270))
[1] 18

# Este é o código de Buritizal (SP) e na PNAD está com 8 números
# Porém este código está errado e o código correto de Buritizal (SP) segue abaixo:

3508207 %in% ipea.pib$V0102
[1] TRUE
35008270 %in% ipea.pib$V0102
[1] FALSE
3508207 %in% ipea.ps$V0102
[1] TRUE
35008270 %in% ipea.ps$V0102
[1] FALSE
```

Supostamente seria por que `UF` e `V0102` compartilham caracteres do banco de dados. Ainda assim, apagando `UF` do dicionário o problema não se resolve. Tem alguém que já trabalhou com a PNAD utilizando como referência (variável de controle) os municípios? Alguma sugestão? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Essa variável v0102 não é o código de município na PNAD. Os municípios não são divulgados porque a pesquisa não é representativa nesse nível. Portanto, não é possível juntar a PNAD com outra base tendo como chave o município.

Comment: Algum dos bancos de dados públicos do IBGE permite chegar ao nível de bairro, mesmo que com nível de significância absurdo?